Adding file to Vertex-AI Bucket
I'm using a notebook in a workbench in Google Cloud Vertex-AI, at some point I want to create a multi-label aiplatform.TextDataset. In order to do so I need first to have my gcs_source I've tried to use a JSON Lines file stored in the same directory as the notebook but aiplatform.TextDataset.create() keeps failing with the following error message:

TypeError: wrap_method() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default_compression'

I think this is because the JSON Lines file that I'm using for the gcs_source to create the TextDataset is not in the Bucket.
Is this the issue? If so, how can I add the JSON to the Bucket?
UPDATE:
That was not the issue, I created the file in the Bucket with:
import json
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('<my_bucket>')
blob = bucket.blob('<my_file>.jsonl')
with blob.open('w') as f:
    for d in data:
        json.dump(d, f)
        f.write('\n')

I checked and the file is properly created in the bucket. But I still get the same error

Hi @Sergio García, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.
